# Expectation of vector-matrix-vector product

Tags: matrices, stochastic-processes, expected-value

I have the following term

$$
E(X_t' \Sigma X_t)
$$

where $X_t$ is a $n \times 1$ vector of random variables and $\Sigma$ is a $n \times n$ matrix of constants. Is it possible to somehow "factor out" the matrix $\Sigma$ out the expectation?

Answer (score 1):

One way to "factor" out the matrix $\Sigma$ is by using the trace operator, Since $X^T \Sigma X$ can be seen as a $1\times 1$ matrix, you have that $X^T \Sigma X=\mathrm{Tr} (X^T \Sigma X)$ and hence
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X^T \Sigma X] &= \mathbb E[\mathrm{Tr}(X^T \Sigma X)]\\
&= \mathbb E[\mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma XX^T )]\\
&= \mathrm{Tr}(\mathbb E[\Sigma XX^T ])\\
&= \mathrm{Tr}(\Sigma \mathbb E[XX^T ])
\end{align*}