# Expectation of matrix-matrix-matrix product

Tags: expected-value, trace, random-matrices

When calculating the [vector-matrix-vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3443594/expectation-of-vector-matrix-vector-product) product
$$\mathbb{E}\left[x_1^TWx_2\right],$$
where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are $n \times 1$ **vectors** of random variables and $W$ is a $n \times n$ constant matrix, one can use the trace to "factor out" $W$ in the following way
$$\begin{align}\mathbb{E}\left[x_1^TWx_2\right]
&= \text{Tr}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[x_1^TWx_2\right]\right)\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\text{Tr}\left(x_1^TWx_2\right)\right]\\
&= \mathbb{E}\left[\text{Tr}\left(Wx_2x_1^T\right)\right]\\
&= \text{Tr}\left(\mathbb{E}\left[Wx_2x_1^T\right]\right)\\
&= \text{Tr}\left(W\mathbb{E}\left[x_2x_1^T\right]\right).
\end{align}$$

However, if we want to calculate
$$\mathbb{E}\left(X_1^TWX_2\right)$$
where now $X_1$ and $X_2$ are random **matrices** of shape $n \times m$, it is not possible to apply the trace operator to factor out $W$ anymore, since the expected value is now a matrix and not a scalar.

How can we calculate this expected value?

Comment: You can use your earlier result to show that the $i, j$ entry of $E[X_1^\top W X_2]$ is $\text{Tr}(W E[x_{2, j} x_{1, i}^\top])$ where $x_{k, i}$ denotes the $i$th column of $X_k$. But not sure if there is a nice way to write the expectation of the entire matrix.